# How to change the name of the day to local language on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, datetime, timezone

I'm use Laravel 5.7, and I have set the date and time using strtotime (doesn't have a problem). My code:

```
{{ date('l', strtotime($job->date_start))}}
```

But what I need is just to change the name of the day into my language, if using the Carbon library it seems too sophisticated because all I need is to change the name of the day. Is there any way to solve what I need?

Thanks.

I expect the output like "Monday" to "Maandag" in Germany, or "Thursday" to "Jueves" in Spanish.

Comment: After searching and some code test, finally I have to use Carbon library. And the "l" was not recognized by Carbon, the library using `"d", "dd", "dddd"`  and the format is `"isoFormat"`. This is the code:`{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->date_start)->isoFormat('dddd')}}` will give you the day. Don't forget to localize in your app.php and other configurations so the Carbon will work on your laravel. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function date() doesn't support any kind of translation.

With Carbon is quite easy:

```
{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($job->date_start)->isoFormat('dddd')}}
```

In this way you get an output according to the locale that is selected at the moment in your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the `->format('dddd')` will give an output bad timezone. So the right choice for that is using `->isoFormat('dddd')`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes indeed, I will fix my answer in case will help somebody else.